# Can't use .Include

Tags: entity-framework

I am following this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using BookService.Models;

namespace BookService.Controllers
{
    public class BooksController : ApiController
    {
        private BookServiceContext db = new BookServiceContext();

        // GET: api/Books
        public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks()
        {
            return db.Books;
                    // new code:
                    .Include(b => b.Author);
        }
```

I says to add `.Include(b => b.Author);` to perform eager loading.
and use  System.Data.Entity.Include
I have done that and I also added the Entityframwork with nuget but I get

> Unexpected token
>   Cannot resolve 'Include'
>   code is unreachable

Am I still missing the Etityframwork.dll and if yes how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can read [from related article of MSDN - Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity
>   also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is
>   achieved by use of the Include method.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                          .ToList(); 

    // Load one blogs and its related posts 
    var blog1 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 

    // Load all blogs and related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blogs2 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include("Posts") 
                          .ToList(); 

    // Load one blog and its related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blog2 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include("Posts") 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

but your code has a typo; you have a `;` too many :

```
return db.Books.Include(b => b.Author);
```

the problem is here :

```
return db.Books; <---
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extra info was really helpful. Also for the code mistake